# Element 'xmlData' can't be allowed in valid XML message. Died. at C:/Perl/site/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 1412

Tags: web-services, perl, client, perl-module

As client I have below code:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
-> uri('$uri_address')
-> on_action( sub { join '/', '$uri_address', $_[1] } )
-> proxy('$url_address');

my $method = SOAP::Data->name('MyMethod')
->attr({xmlns => '$uri_address'});

#The parameters are held in @params
my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(xmlData => $xml_string));

my $result = $soap
                        ->soapversion('1.2')
                        ->call($method => @params);

i    f ($result->fault)
{
   print $result->faultstring;
}
else
{
   print $result->result;
}
```

I used `+trace=>all`, and in log I got:

```
SOAP::Transport::new: ()
SOAP::Serializer::new: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::new: ()
SOAP::Parser::new: ()
SOAP::Lite::new: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Lite::call: ()
SOAP::Serializer::envelope: ()
SOAP::Serializer::envelope: SOAP::Data=HASH(0x35bb7f4) SOAP::Data=HASH(0x35bba94)
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
SOAP::Data::new: ()
Element 'xmlData' can't be allowed in valid XML message. Died. at C:/Perl/site/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 1412.
SOAP::Lite::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Serializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Parser::DESTROY: ()
```

Any one have solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[XML §2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn)

> Names beginning with the string "xml" […] are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.